# Why sending a PUT request as plain/text is not accepted by ASP.NET Core?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, httprequest

I'm trying to send a PUT request that contains a string.

The request is sent from client that is in Angular to server that is an ASP.NET Core Controller. The request header is `text/plain`.

To make ASP.NET Core accept `text/plain`, I had to follow [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers) tutorial, that works only if I send the request with Postman:
 [image]
When I try to sent the same request from client to server it doesn't work, the request not event trigger the brake point from `RawRequestBodyFormatter` class.

Angular service:

```ts
export class LendedBookService {
  private baseUrl: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:55152/';
  }

  public sendReminder(lendedBookId: string): Observable<any> {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
    return this.httpClient.put<string>(this.baseUrl + 'api/lendedBook/sendReminder', lendedBookId, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }
}
```

ASP.NET Core Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class LendedBookController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Libranian libranian;

    public LendedBookController(Libranian libranian)
    {
        this.libranian = libranian;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IAsyncResult> SendReminder([FromBody]string lendedBookId)
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkLocator.GetUnitOfWork())
        {
            if (await libranian.NotifyToReturnLend(new Guid(lendedBookId)))
            {
                return Task.Run(() => NoContent());
            }

            return Task.Run(() => StatusCode(500));
        }
    }
}
```

**What should I do or what I did wrong sending a `text/plain` request in this case?**
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any error in the console? after API call

Comment: @PrashantPimpale nope. Also Fiddler didn't find the request.

Comment: Anything in the network tab?

Comment: I would suggest to make it as JSON instead of plain text which will be better in term of maintaining and change

Comment: @PrashantPimpale in ASP.NET strings can't be sent as `application/JSON`.

Comment: Then make a class with one property